# Android: Basic User Login Failure

Tags: android

Good Evening

I am attempting to create a simple android application that asks the user for login information; the details of which are stored in an SQL database.

However the php displays an error Notice: Undefined variable: username and Notice: Undefined variable: password.

I believe the error can be traced to the Java class responsible for connecting to the database. Specifically the String username, and password.

```
protected String doInBackground**(String... arg0)** {

        try{
            **String username = (String)arg0[0];**
            **String password = (String)arg0[1];**

            String link="//Removed//";
            String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

            wr.write( data );
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

}
```

Because I am very new to android I have been following the http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm 
guide in order to create the system. I would greatly appreciate any help with the matter.

Thank you.

PHP CODE

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("//","//","//","//");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$username = $_POST['username'];

$password = $_POST['password'];


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Role FROM my_db WHERE 
Username='$username' and Password='$password'");


$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];

if($data){
echo $data;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Hi, it seems the GET parameter names doesn't match. Did you write the php side too? Make sure you use the same keys on both sides.

Comment: By the way, its not a good idea to send your credentials over URL.

Comment: Hi cylon thanks for the response, the php code I use the template given on the website only editing in my SQL credentials

Comment: Can you post the PHP code as well?